# I by mistake deleted usr/share/java in ubuntu16..04. How to fix it?

Tags: 16.04

By mistake I have deleted  usr/share/java. How to fix it?

Comment: Reinstall Java.

Answer (score 2):

If you had (parts of) a Java installation at `/usr/share/java*` that means you installed Java through the package manager. There are a few independent Java packages available in Ubuntu and I don't know which one(s) you installed because you don't tell us. However you can reinstall any package with

```
sudo apt install --reinstall <PACKAGE...>
```

to restore missing or corrupted files.

You can find out which files of all installed packages ought to reside in `/usr/share/java` and their respective packages with:

```
dpkg-query -S /usr/share/java
```

You can even use the result of that command to install all of the listed packages right away:

```sh
dpkg-query -S /usr/share/java | sed -e 's/:.*$//;s/, /\n/g' | xargs -rd '\n' -- sudo apt install --reinstall
```